# Is this a subordinate clause?

Tags: clauses

> I eat pizza, and I eat chicken.

If the clause contains 'and', should it be called a *subordinate* clause or *coordinate* clause?

Comment: Your example is a coordination of main clauses: [I eat pizza], [and I eat chicken].

Answer (score 1):

> [*I eat pizza*] [*and I eat chicken*].

There's no subordinate clause.

This is a coordination consisting of the two bracketed main clauses.

Note that the coordinator "and" is part of the second coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

According to Cambridge Dictionary, **a subordinate clause** (also called a dependent clause) is a clause that cannot form a sentence on its own but can be joined to a main clause to form a sentence.
***I didn’t go to work because I wasn’t feeling very well*** (We can't just put aside the main clause "***I didn’t go to work***" and leave only "***because I wasn’t feeling very well***". The subordinate part doesn't make any sense without the main clause).

*He studied violin and mathematics **before taking a medical degree and doing postgraduate work in biophysics at Harvard.***

The link between a subordinate clause and an independent clause will often be a subordinating conjunction or a relative pronoun: after, although, as, because, before, if, that, what, when, where, which, who.

**A coordinate clause** is one of two or more clauses in a sentence that are of equal importance and usually joined by and, or, or but.

***I’ll take the train and you can take the car.***

Answer (score 0):

It is a coordinate clause.

A subordinate clause could be made by exchanging *and* for an adverb such as *so*, *since*, or *when*.

*I eat pizza, so I eat chicken.*

*I eat pizza, since I eat chicken.*

*I eat pizza, when I eat chicken.*